# Enviar fecha y hora al controlador de asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Buen Día, tengo un pequeño problema con las fechas al enviarlas al controlador(POST) de la vista.
Este es mi formulario:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/home/insert" novalidate>
<div class="col-sm-3 input-group" style="float: left;">
   <input type="text" class="date start form-control" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" required style="border-right: 0;"value="@string.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", Model.evento[0].Fecha_Inicio)" />
   <span class="input-group-addon fui-calendar" style="background: transparent; color: #bdc3c7;"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 input-group" style="float: left; width: 20.9%;">
    <input type="text" class="time start form-control" placeholder="Hora Inicio" required style="border-right: 0;" value="@string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", Model.evento[0].Fecha_Inicio)" />
    <span class="input-group-addon fui-time" style="background: transparent; color: #bdc3c7;"></span>
</div>
</form>
```

Este es mi modelo:

```
public class insertEvento
{
    public string Fecha_Inicio { get; set; }
    public string Hora_Inicio { get; set; }
}
```

De esa manera funciona bien pero lo que realmente quiero es enviar la fecha a mi modelo de esta forma

```
public class insertEvento
{
    public DateTime Fecha_Inicio { get; set; }
}
```

Pero sin tener que modificar mis campos del formulario ya que estoy usando librerías de terceros que en el campo fecha únicamente me da las fecha y en el campo hora solo meda la hora en formato de 24 hrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto sucede por la cultura aplicado al sitio, podrias intentar definiendo en el `web.config` la linea

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-ES" />
```

con esto si ingresas una fecha con formato `dd/MM/yyyy` deberia reconocerla y poder asignarla en el action.

Si con esto no funciona vas a tener que definir un ModelBinder custom que permita parsear la fecha que recibe como string

[Globalizing DateTime and Decimal in ASP.NET MVC Using ModelBinder](https://blog.murilogomes.com/2015/03/24/globalizing-datetime-and-decimal-in-asp-net-mvc-using-modelbinder/)

[Globalization: Model binding DateTimes with ASP.Net MVC](http://www.hackered.co.uk/articles/globalization-model-binding-datetimes-with-asp-net-mvc)

esta forma es algo mas particular ya que estarias tomando el valor y validando la fecha desde codigo para adaptarla al tipo de dato

Comment: Creo que no exprese bien mi objetivo, lo que intento hacer es tomar tanto la fecha del input y la hora del otro input, con el fin de enviarlos juntos al segundo modelo en forma de datetime

Comment: No estoy totalmente satisfecho con la respuesta, pero sin embargo me soluciono la mayor parte del problema, lo único que me hizo falta capturar fue la hora pero por cambios en el proyectos ya no lo necesito y así que la solución fue al 100%, Gracias Leandro.